# Navigate on AngularJS + Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: angularjs, mobile, kendo-ui, navigation, kendo-mobile

I am very new to AngularJS + Kendo UI Mobile.

How can I navigate to a page from angular controller?

I tried this code:

var App = $("#app").data("kendoMobileApplication");
App.navigate("#menuCategories");

but I get this error: "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress"

and about ngRoute I see:

"The mobile application instantiates and maintains its own routing mechanism based on the router component, which automatically matches and instantiates views when navigating. ... Note that AngularJS routing mechanisms are not supported"

Thanks in advance

Sorry for bad english ..

Naomi.

Answer (score 1):

telerik team answer me, the solution is:
kendo.mobile.application.navigate(viewName) (without '#' sign)

Comment: can u tell me pls, what you mean by viewName; the name attribute the mobile.view or the id ? and did you include the viewName file in your index-html or how did u done ?